# Compare files with Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare Bro/Zeek logs against a second file to determine if IP addresses or domain names from second file exist in the zeek logs. I want to be able to pass conn/dns.log as a parameter (compressed/uncompressed) to the script and have it parsed with duplicates removed and compared to the second file as a second parameter. The final result should only show the file name and the matching IP/Domains between the two files.

I've made an attempt below to accomplish this however,I can only cut successfully I see the sort isn't working as I'm still getting duplicates and I'm not sure how to do the comparison against the second parameter.

If there is a better or more efficient way I'm all for it. Thanks.

compare.sh <conn.log/dns.log> indicators.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

# Compare files to see if they have matching strings.

clog=conn.log
dlog=dns.log

if [ $1 == $clog ]
then
        cut -f3 $1;cut -f5 $1 | sort -u | grep -Fwf $2
        echo "We have a match in $1"
elif
        [ $1 == $dlog ]
then
        cut -f10 $1|sort -u|grep -Fwf $2
        echo "We have a match in $1"
else
        echo "No matches"
fi

echo "Comparison complete"
```

Below is some example data and expected output:

Example: conn.log

```
1.2.3.4    1.2.3.5
172.3.2.4  10.2.20.50
...
```

Example: indicators

```
1.2.3.4
10.20.20.50
172.3.2.4
...
```

Expected Output:

```
1.2.3.4
172.3.2.4
We have a match in conn.log
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: If `indicators.txt` is sorted, the `comm` command would be better than `grep`.

Comment: @JamesBrown, added sample data and output to question.

Comment: If I were to turn parameter 1 to a compressed file (i.e, conn.log.gz) how would this script change? Would I have to pass it to zcat somewhere in the script?

Answer (score 0):

For `conn.log` you're only piping the second `cut` to `sort` and `grep`. You need to group the two `cut` commands to get both of them piped.

```
{ cut -f3 "$1";cut -f5 "$1"; } | sort -u | grep -Fwf "$2"
```

Another option would be to use `grep` instead of running `cut` twice:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $3; print $5}' "$1" | sort -u | grep -Fwf "$2"
```

Comment: I tried the first command it doesn't output the IP/domains. However, the AWK command does exactly what I want.

Comment: If I were to turn parameter 1 to a compressed file (i.e, conn.log.gz) how would this script change? I tried running with a compressed file that should have a match however, it says, "No matches." I need to be able to pass compressed/uncompressed files as a parameter. Thanks.

Comment: `zcat conn.log.gz | awk ...`

Comment: thanks that did the trick I added this as an additional elif to my script.